# xarray - select the data at specific x AND y coordinates

Tags: python, select, python-xarray, indices

When selecting data with xarray at x,y locations, I get data for any pair of x,y. I would like to have a 1-D array not a 2-D array from the selection. Is there an efficient way to do this? (For now I am doing it with a for-loop...)

x = [x1,x2,x3,x4]
y = [y1,y2,y3,y4]

DS = 2-D array

```
subset = Dataset.sel(longitude=x, latitude=y, method='nearest')
```

To rephrase, I would like to have the dataset at [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4] not at other location i.e. [x1,y2].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A list of points can be selected along multiple indices if the indexers are `DataArray`s with a common dimension. This will result in the array being reindexed along the indexers' common dimension.

Straight from the docs on [More Advanced Indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing):

```
In [78]: da = xr.DataArray(np.arange(56).reshape((7, 8)), dims=['x', 'y'])

In [79]: da
Out[79]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 7, y: 8)>
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
       [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
       [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y

In [80]: da.isel(x=xr.DataArray([0, 1, 6], dims='z'),
   ....:         y=xr.DataArray([0, 1, 0], dims='z'))
   ....: 
Out[80]: 
<xarray.DataArray (z: 3)>
array([ 0,  9, 48])
Dimensions without coordinates: z
```

The indexing array can also be easily pulled out of a pandas `DataFrame`, with something like `da.sel(longitude=df.longitude.to_xarray(), latitude=df.latitude.to_xarray())`, which will result in the `DataArray` being reindexed by the *DataFrame's* index.

So in your case, rather than selecting with the lists or arrays `x, y`, turn them into DataArrays with a common dim - let's call it `location`:

```py
x = xr.DataArray([x1,x2,x3,x4], dims=['location'])
y = xr.DataArray([y1,y2,y3,y4], dims=['location'])
```

Now your selection will work as you hope:

```py
ds.sel(longitude=x, latitude=y, method='nearest')
```