# Bird observation dataset to include temperature and precipitation data

Tags: temperature

Im new in this field and this is my first project on this area. I have a global bird observation dataset that doesnt include temperature and precipitation data. i have found global precipitation and temperature data but all of them are of different dimensions(lets say my dataset includes 130000 observations with coords, temperature data have dimensions(sizes): lat(360), lon(720), time(907), precipitation has dimensions(sizes): lat(180), lon(360), time(1590)). My understanding on the process is that I should create a grid system with my bird dataset coords and apply gradually the temperature and then the precipitation data. I also need to do this in batches in order for colab not to crash. Can someone relevant to this field shed some light to my thinking?

```
file_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/datasets/precip.comb.v2020to2019-v2020monitorafter.total.nc'
precipitation_data = nc.Dataset(file_path, 'r')
print(precipitation_data)

file_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/datasets/air.mon.mean.nc'
temperature_data = nc.Dataset(file_path, 'r')
print(temperature_data)

latitude = df['decimalLatitude']
longitude = df['decimalLongitude']

batch_size = 1000

temperature_values = []
precipitation_values = []
```

Comment: This code isn't reproducible, so it's hard to be specific, but if you're using python I would recommend the xarray package to read the netcdf files and the pandas package to read tabular data. Then you can use something like shown in this answer to extract the coordinates you want from the gridded data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72179547/12133280